# Grab area of body background to use within a canvas area

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to canvas and I have somewhat of an idea of how it works from source to source, however what I'm trying to achieve is somewhat dynamic. I want to load a body background on my page (responsive using a position center with cover) and extract an area to then manipulate with a greensock card flip.

Essentially, I would have a wooden panel background, and I want to create secret panel doors that will rotate on hover or click to show content behind them.

To be explicit, I would have a BS row with col-sm-4's with a bottle on a shelf, like a western saloon. When you hover it would take that background, with the png bottle on top of it, and copy it allowing me to rotate it, to reveal a short blurb about a product.

I dont like coming straight here which is why I have so few posts/score..but this is really stumping me. ANy help in the right direction I would gladly "tip" for, if it works out. Thanks everyone.

Here's my codepen as of now...

```
`http://codepen.io/dtek516/pen/vKLOBp`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tweenlite can (indirectly) animate Canvas drawings...**

- Canvas drawings can be controlled using a JavaScript object.
- Tweenlite can animate properties on a JavaScript object.

Taken together, you can use Tweenlite to animate the properties of a JavaScript object which, in turn, controls the drawings on the Canvas.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;

var wheel={
    cx:cw/2,
    cy:ch/2,
    radius:Math.min(cw,ch)/2-20,
    startAngle:PI/4,
    angle:PI/4,
    draw:function(){
        ctx.translate(this.cx,this.cy);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0,0,this.radius,0,PI2);
        ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
        ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle='red';
        ctx.font='18px verdana';
        ctx.textBaseline='middle';
        ctx.fillText('You Win!',40,0);
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cw/2,ch/2);
        ctx.lineTo(cw/2+30,ch/2);
        ctx.strokeStyle='green';
        ctx.stroke();
    },
}

var tl=TweenLite.to(wheel,5,{
    paused:true,
    angle:PI2*2,
    ease:"Quart.easeOut",
    onUpdate:function(){this.target.draw();},
    onComplete:function(){console.log('complete',wheel);}
  }
);


wheel.draw();

$('#play').click(function(){ tl.play(); });

$('#replay').click(function(){  tl.restart(); });
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<button id=play>Play</button>
<button id=replay>Replay</button>
<br><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**But it might be easier to do your hover-flip-reveal like this (no Canvas required):**

- Divide your background into 8 img elements. The background is 4 img's and the revealed "information cards" are 4 images.
- Listen for hover / blur events on those background img elements
- On hover, use Greensock's Tweenlite to animate the hovered background image until it's edge-on to the user.
- Then Tweenlite animate "information card" img starting from an edge-on rotation until it's flat to the user (flat==fully revealed).
- On blur, reverse the 2 revealing animations so the background img is again shown.

You can use Greensock's TimelineLite to schedule & run the 2-part animation.